# Why function relates to code that is not in function?

Tags: symfony

I have the following controller:

```
<?php

namespace Dev\TaskBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Dev\TaskBundle\Entity\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
  /**
    * Redirects to directory where you can input new password
    *
    * @Route("/{id}", name="user_update")
    */

    public function userUpdatePanel($id)
    {

        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DevTaskBundle:User')->find($id);
        return $this->render('DevTaskBundle:User:userUpdate.html.twig', array('user' => $user));

    }

   /**
    * Updates password of the user
    *
    * @Route("/updatePassword", name="updatePass_action")
    */


    public function passUpdateAction(Request $request)
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $id = $request->get('id');
        $user = new User();
        $user = $em->getRepository('DevTaskBundle:User')->find($id);
        $password = $request->get('passInput');
        $user->setPassword($password);
        $em->flush();

        $users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DevTaskBundle:User')->findAll();
        return $this->render('DevTaskBundle:User:accounts.html.twig', array('users' => $users));

    }

}
```

Here is form from userUpdate.html.twig

```
<form action="{{ path('updatePass_action') }}" method="POST">


<div>
        Username: {{ user.username }}
    </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{user.id}}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="passInput">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="passInput" name="passInput" value="{{ user.password }}">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Change</button>
    </form>
```

and when I proceed to change the password I receive such error

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("username") on a null variable in DevTaskBundle:User:userUpdate.html.twig at line 23
```

After changing the password I want to render accounts.html.twig so why there is the error about userUpdate? What is wrong here?

Part of accounts.html.twig with twig scripts:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Login</th>
        <th>Hasło</th>
        <th>Narzędzia</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for user in users %}
    <tr>

        <td>
            {{  user.username }}
        </td>

        <td>
            {{  user.password }}
        </td>

        <td>        
            <a href="{{ path('user_update', {'id': user.id}) }}" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil linkDeco" ></span>
            </a>
        {% if user.status == 1 %}    
            <a href="{{ path('deleteAction', {'name': 'User' ,'direction': 'account_panel' , 'id': user.id}) }}" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash linkDeco"></span>
            </a>
        {% endif %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT
problem must be related to userUpdate.html.twig because when I deleted

```
<div>
            Username: {{ user.username }}
        </div>
```

I have the error

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("id") on a null variable in DevTaskBundle:User:userUpdate.html.twig at line 24
```

Any idea why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine `find` method return array of objects, use `findOne` instead of `find` when you expecting only one result.

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DevTaskBundle:User')->findOneById($id);
```